# Selecting bones with the same name

Tags: python, rigging, armature, bones, select

I'm writing a little picker for Blender. The principle of operation is simple. I select some armatures, go into pose mode. If I select bones, then bones with the same name in other armatures become selected.

```
import bpy

def picker(scene):
    selected_obj = [obj.name for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects]
    selected_arm = (bpy.data.armatures[selected_obj])
    selected_bones = [bone.name for bone in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones]
    for bone in selected_arm.bones:
        if bone.name in selected_bones:
            bone.select = True            
            
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(picker)
```

The script works if you specify the name of the armature, for example:

```
selected_arm = bpy.data.armatures['Armature.001']
```

But I don't know how to make it work for any number of armatures with any names.

Answer (score 3):

I think this script should do what you want.

```py
import bpy

armatures = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == "ARMATURE"]
# If you want to select only from selected armatures, use the next line instead.
# armatures = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == "ARMATURE"]
selected_bones = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones

for armature in armatures:
    for selected_bone in selected_bones:
        bone = armature.pose.bones.get(selected_bone.name)
        if bone:
            bone.bone.select = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I need!

Answer (score -1):

I would iterate through all selected objects and check if their o.data was of type armature. Then, if it was, run the bone matching loop on it.